# Aut *celer* aut *vēlōx*?

Tags: meaning, word-comparison, adjective, word-choice

*Celer* and *vēlōx* are often treated as synonymous. I feel certain that I learned the technical distinction between them once: that *celer* was potential speed, while *vēlōx* was actual speed. So Usain Bolt sitting on the couch would be *celer* (he's capable of moving very quickly), but not *vēlōx* (he isn't moving quickly at the moment). Conversely, stones being whipped around in a hurricane would be *vēlōx* (they're going really fast) but not *celer* (it's not their natural state).

However, neither Döderlein nor L&S makes any mention of this. Is my memory deceiving me? Or have others heard about this distinction as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *celer* was potential speed (…) but not *vēlōx*

A counterexample can be found in Cæsar's *Commentarii de bello Gallico*:

> Genus hoc erat pugnae, quo se Germani exercuerant: equitum milia erant VI, totidem numero **pedites velocissimi** ac fortissimi, quos ex omni copia singuli singulos suae salutis causa delegerant (…)
>
> *Commentarii de bello Gallico*, I, 48

However, *celer* and *velox* haven't exactly the same meaning, as explained in this book I've just found:

[image: Celer vs velox 1]
[image: Celer vs velox 2]

*In* Dumesnil, *[Latin Synonyms with Their Different Significations and Examples Taken from the Best Latin Authors](https://books.google.fr/books?id=9YkSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA138)*, 1809

Comment: "Expeditious" strikes me as a pretty creative translation of *celer*, but I think especially the Horace example (*oderunt sedatum celeres*) shows an example where *velox* could not be substituted. There's an inherent danger to coming up with "rules" (like "potential speed") for words that differ more in *nuance* than *meaning*, like English "swift" and "fast."